# Using java mail receives another mail content type when it is called from a module

Tags: java, android, email

I have an Android project where I'm using java mail for receiving mails from a gmail account.

First, I implemented a class for handling the receiving of mails. I know, each mail has its own
type of content (String, MultiPart, ...). I'm only interested in mails with a content type of String.

Ok, so I instantiate my receiving class, call the receiving method and get all mails from my gmail account with a content type of String.
So far, so good. This works for me perfectly.

But, when I create an Android module (.aar file) from the receiving class (same code, no changes) and import it to another Android project, there is a strange behavior of receiving mails.

After I imported the Android module, I instantiate the receiving class, call the receiving method, I get the same mails as before, but now they have 
a content type of QPDecoderStream.

For a better understanding, here is my receiving code:

```
public List<Mail> receive() {

    List<Mail> mailList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", mConfig.getStoreProtocol());

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);

        mStore = session.getStore();
        mStore.connect(mConfig.getImapHost(), mUsername, mPassword);

        mInbox = mStore.getFolder(mConfig.getStoreFolder());
        mInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        Message[] messages = mInbox.getMessages();

        for (Message message : messages) {

            String bodyPart = "";
            Object content = message.getContent();

                // Check for mail content type
                if (content instanceof String) {

                    // This code is executed by "normal" method call within an Android class

                    Logger.info(MailReceiver.class, "Mail content is String");
                    bodyPart = (String) content;
                } else if (content instanceof QPDecoderStream) {

                    // This code is executed by method call within an Android module

                    Logger.info(MailReceiver.class, "Mail content is QPDecoderStream");

                    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream((InputStream) content);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    int c;

                    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {

                        out.write(c);
                    }

                    bodyPart = new String(out.toByteArray());
                }

            Mail mail = new Mail();

            mail.setSubject(message.getSubject());
            mail.setDate(message.getSentDate().toString());
            mail.setContent(bodyPart);

            mailList.add(mail);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Logger.error(MailReceiver.class, "Exception occurred while receiving mail: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {

        closeInbox();
        closeStore();
    }

    return mailList;
}
```

I hope I could explain my problem sufficiently and I would be glad for some advices.

Thanks in advance.

Chris P.